# Objective-C command line arguments starting with <

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, command-line-arguments

I'm parsing command line arguments using standardUserDefaults like suggested in another question, this works in 99% of cases however when a parameter starts with < it fails.

Works:

```
./prog -arg1 'hello<>asdf
```

Doesn't work:

```
./prog -arg1 '<hello'
```

When the supplied argument starts with < then [defaults stringForKey:key] just returns NULL. Basically pretty much everything seems to work unless it starts with < and I don't think it has anything to do with bash/escaping/pipes.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSLog(@"arg1: %@", [defaults stringForKey:@"arg1"]);
//        NSLog(@"%@", [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you've found a bug. The behaviour you report is what happens and a quick check through likely other special characters also shows that values starting with a dash, e.g. `./prog -arg1 '-fred'`, also don't work - other symbols such as '>', ';' and '|' do work.

The [minimal documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW6) provides no reason for this behaviour.

Report a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

In your code you can process the arguments yourself. You can either use the `argc` & `argv` if you wish to use C-style strings for parsing; or `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments` will give you them as an `NSArray` of `NSString`.

HTH

Comment: Okay thanks, I don't know much about Objective-c/NSUserDefaults so I wasn't sure if it's some weird special behaviour or restriction that could be turned off and couldn't find anything in the docs. I just happened to encounter that problem today while using the open source "terminal-notifier" tool and hoped that would be an easy fix.